# Why is EditTextPreference setText("string") only working internally on start? I'm trying to set a value when the user enters an empty string

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences

I have my **MainActivity**, that calls my settings Activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_SETTINGS);
```

**"device_name"** is an EditTextPreference with no default value or value.

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="device_name"
    android:title="Device Name"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:capitalize="words"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLines="1" />
```

My **SettingsActivity** extends **PreferenceActivity**.

---

**onPostCreate** I call `bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("device_name"));`

```
private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}
```

---

The listener's primary focus is setting the preferences summary, for the editTextPreference I was to check if the value is null or empty and replace it with `Build.MODEL`.

```
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

            // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
            preference.setSummary(
                    index >= 0
                            ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                            : null);
        }
        else if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference)
        {
            EditTextPreference editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) preference;

            //editTextPreference.getText();

            if (stringValue.trim().equals("") || stringValue.equals(null))
            {
                Log.i("valuesUpdate", "Yes");

                editTextPreference.setText(Build.MODEL + "_1");

                Log.i("valuesUpdate", editTextPreference.getTitle() + " = " + editTextPreference.getText());

                editTextPreference.setSummary(Build.MODEL + "_2");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("valuesUpdate", "No?");
                editTextPreference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }
        }
        else {
            // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
            // simple string representation.

            preference.setSummary(stringValue);

        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

---

When I go to get the setting from my **MainActivity**, i use the following code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.getAppContext());
String android_id = sharedPreferences.getString("device_name", "UNKNOWN_DEVICE");
```

---

1. When I first start the application, **android_id** returns "UNKNOWN_DEVICE" as expected.
2. After I open/close the **SettingsActivity**, **android_id** returns "XT1060_1" as expected.
3. If I click to edit the setting **"device_name"**, it populates "XT1060_1" in the text field as expected as well.

---

**THE ISSUE**: When I edit the setting **"device_name"** to be an empty string, and click "OK" on my device, the summary for "Device Name" shows "XT1060_2" as expected and the log shows:

```
valuesUpdate﹕ Yes
valuesUpdate﹕ Device Name = XT1060_1
```

(so **getText()** is working just fine in **SettingsActivity** directly after **setText()**)

But when I reopen the setting for **"device_name"**, the text field is still empty.

As well, once I close the **SettingsActivity** and try to obtain the setting from the **MainActivity**, **android_id** returns an empty string as well.

Once I reopen the **SettingsActivity** again, it does work (just like point 2 above).

Answer (score 0):

onPref`erenceChangedListener`'s `onPreferenceChange` method is called before state changes in `SharedPreferences`. 
So.

1. **onPreferenceChange** (with empty string)
2. you set new text on **EditTextPreference** (here I think **onPreferenceChange** should be called recursively but it seems to not be called
3. then changes with empty string are applied from 1) point i.e. empty string saved.

I think you could **return false** in the case you modify preference value to prevent overriding your default value by empty string.

```
if (stringValue.trim().equals("") || stringValue.equals(null))
            {
                Log.i("valuesUpdate", "Yes");

                editTextPreference.setText(Build.MODEL + "_1");

                Log.i("valuesUpdate", editTextPreference.getTitle() + " = " + editTextPreference.getText());

                editTextPreference.setSummary(Build.MODEL + "_2");

                // HERE 
                return false; 
            }
```